# Execute program with different parameters and storing results in txt file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to execute a program (let's say myApp) in the ubuntu shell. 
Normally myApp is called like this: `myApp /path/to/file1 /path/tofile2` the output is a matrix which will be printed on the standard output.

What i want to do is to execute myApp for all files in a directory and save the output in a txt file. The last part, i hope is easy which i intend to do with `myApp /path/to/file1 /path/tofile2 > myOutputfile.txt`.

I am really stuck with calling all files automatically.
If have tried to do this:

```
for i in $(ls /tmp/ch0_*000000{0..483..4}.pcd);
    do 
    f1=$i    
    f2=$i+1 # i also tried f2=i+1
    myApp /tmp/$f1 /tmp/$f2 > myOutput.txt
done
```

so my problem is that i cannot get to the next filename in the list to pass it to myApp. what i am doing so far is adding '+1' to the existing file string.
How can i get the next file from the returned ls output?
thanks!

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Is `ch0_*000000{0..483..4}.pcd` even supposed to work? can you tell us how are the files present under `/tmp`?

Comment: the files in /tmp look like this:
`ch0_000000000.pcd
ch0_000000001.pcd
...
ch0_000000010.pcd
...
ch0_000000483.pcd
`
and yes it works if i print every 4th filename with echo.

Comment: and what did you meant by `{0..483..4}`

Comment: Another great resource http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the link Inian gave -- [why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- you cannot get the "next" item in a bash `for` loop (at least, to my knowledge).

What you *can* do is remember the *last* item.

```
unset last_i
# Fudging the wildcarding a bit as it is unclear
# what your `ls` was supposed to achieve.
# This is assuming at least one matching file exists,
# otherwise you will get one loop with, literally,
# i=/tmp/ch0_*.pcd
for i in /tmp/ch0_*.pcd
do
    if [[ ! -z $last_i ]]
    then
        myApp $last_i $i >> myOutput.txt
    fi
    last_i="$i"
done
```

Note:

- Use direct wildcarding instead of `$(ls ...)`.
- No semicolon after `for`.
- No need for `$f1`, `$f2`.
- With `> myOutput.txt`, your output file will be overwritten for each loop; with `>>` output will be *appended*. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: thanks DevSolar, it kind of works. i get this message when i try to run the script `syntax error near unexpected token `fi'` .
if i comment the if part out it runs through but of course the first time i can only parse one filename.

Comment: @Sven0: You could make the output file name be based on the processed file (`> $(basename $i .pcd)_out.txt`).

Comment: true, but in my case it is actually more convenient to have it in one file. 
Could you please help me with the `if ... fi` problem that i seem to have? Why does the bash not recognized the `fi` command?

Comment: @Sven0: Uh... forgot the `then`. Fixed.

Comment: yes, i looked it up how to define an if statement in bash-programming and fixed it myself. thanks anyway for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Solution that worked for me:

```
for i in {0..3..1}; do 
    f1="/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/ch0_000000$i.txt"    
    k=$(($i+1)) 
    f2="/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests/ch0_000000$k.txt"
    #myApp /tmp/$f1 /tmp/$f2 > myOutput.txt
    echo "F1 = $f1 and F2=$f2"
    ls $f1
    ls $f2
done
```

In your case should work like this:

```
for i in {0..483..4}; do 
f1="/tmp/ch0_000000$i.pcd"    #or "/tmp/ch0_$i.pcd" , not clear how your files are numbered.
k=$(($i+1)) 
f2="/tmp/ch0_000000$k.pcd"    #or "/tmp/ch0_$k.pcd" , not clear how your files are numbered.
myApp $f1 $f2 > myOutput.txt
#echo "F1 = $f1 and F2=$f2"
#ls $f1
#ls $f2
done
```